# Android SQLite database query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm creating an android app that requires database connectivity, for which I'm using the inbuilt SQLiteDatabase class. My database has been created using the following statement:-

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactsMain",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
db.execSQL("Create Table Contacts (name Text, phno Text PRIMARY KEY, important Integer)");
```

'important' has values of either 0 or 1, based on whether the contact is important. To update this value, I'm using the following code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    String ph = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phno"));
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
    val.put("important",1);
    String query = "update Contacts set important = 1 where phno=" + ph + ";";
    db.update("Contacts", val, query, null);
    c.close();
    db.close();
}
```

db and c have been initialized as follows:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("ContactsMain",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Contacts",null);
```

Problem is, when I click on an item in the list, the value of 'important' is set to 1 for all contacts, not just the one selected. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: Justgive important value as dynamically

Comment: @ADR : Could you elaborate? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
val.put("important", 1);
db.update("Contacts", val, "phno=?", new String[] {ph});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


  c.moveToPosition(position);
  String ph = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phno"));

  String where = "phno=?";
  String[] whereArgs = new String[] {ph};    

  ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
  val.put("important",1);

  db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, val, where, whereArgs);
  c.close();
  db.close();

}
```

Comment: This will update all the records in the database, not just one.

Comment: This looks good to me, except that I do not think you should be closing the cursor here.

Comment: All the records are being updated, and that is the problem! I want only the item selected from the list to be updated. How do I do that? I tried the approach given in the first answer, still didn't work.